# Python math operation until 'n' is pressed

Tags: python, loops, input, while-loop

I wanted to create python script that will help me with my math problem. I have formula that I want to use on my problem, I just wanted to save some time because I need to calculate with different values for at least 20 times.

I created this function:

```
def vypocet():
    y2 = float(input("Zadaj hodnotu y2: "))
    y1 = float(input("Zadaj hodnotu y1: "))
    x2 = float(input("Zadaj hodnotu x2: "))
    x1 = float(input("Zadaj hodnotu x1: "))
    x = float(input("Zadaj hodnotu x: "))
    vysledok = (y2-y1)/(x2-x1)*(x-x1)+y1
    return vysledok
```

It is working as expected.

Now I need to create a loop, that will repeat this calculation until User will press "N".
I need to create one more var, that will be expecting 'Y' or 'N' from user and after this input it will end or repeat calculation.

I tried while cycle, but I was not succesfull.

Please help me.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

do I understand correctly that you want something like that?

```
   def vypocet():
    dalsi_opakovani = "Y"
    while dalsi_opakovani != "N":
        y2 = float(input("Zadaj hodnotu y2: "))
        y1 = float(input("Zadaj hodnotu y1: "))
        x2 = float(input("Zadaj hodnotu x2: "))
        x1 = float(input("Zadaj hodnotu x1: "))
        x = float(input("Zadaj hodnotu x: "))
        vysledok = (y2-y1)/(x2-x1)*(x-x1)+y1
        print(vysledok)
        dalsi_opakovani = input("Chcete dalsi opakovani vypoctu? Y/N ")
    return vysledok
    
vypocet()
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if thats what you want.

```
def vypocet():
    y2 = float(input("Zadaj hodnotu y2: "))
    y1 = float(input("Zadaj hodnotu y1: "))
    x2 = float(input("Zadaj hodnotu x2: "))
    x1 = float(input("Zadaj hodnotu x1: "))
    x = float(input("Zadaj hodnotu x: "))
    vysledok = (y2-y1)/(x2-x1)*(x-x1)+y1
    return vysledok

while input("Continue?") != "N":
    print(vypocet())
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what you are looking for:

```
def vypocet():
   y2 = float(input("Zadaj hodnotu y2: "))
   y1 = float(input("Zadaj hodnotu y1: "))
   x2 = float(input("Zadaj hodnotu x2: "))
   x1 = float(input("Zadaj hodnotu x1: "))
   x = float(input("Zadaj hodnotu x: "))
   vysledok = (y2-y1)/(x2-x1)*(x-x1)+y1
   return vysledok

while True:
    print(vypocet())
    x=input("Do you want to continue (Y/N): ")
    if(x=="N"):
        break
```

The program will ask an input

> Do you want to continue (Y/N): N

When N is provided as input, it will stop otherwise it will take back to the function, resulting in task repetition.

Answer (score 0):

Add this while loop to your code, this should work.

```
while True:
    choice = input('Do you want to calculate?(y/n): ')
    if choice == 'n' or choice == 'N':
        break
    elif choice == 'y' or choice == 'Y':
        vypocet()
    else:
        print('Please enter y or n')
```

Answer (score 0):

If I didn't understand wrongly:

```
def vypocet():

  a =''
  while not (a == 'n'): #if condition not satisfied, continue below action

    y2 = float(input("Zadaj hodnotu y2: "))
    y1 = float(input("Zadaj hodnotu y1: "))
    x2 = float(input("Zadaj hodnotu x2: "))
    x1 = float(input("Zadaj hodnotu x1: "))
    x = float(input("Zadaj hodnotu x: "))
    vysledok = (y2-y1)/(x2-x1)*(x-x1)+y1

    print (vysledok) #result
    
    a = input('continue y or n: ') #y results in condition not satisfied, continue looping

vypocet()
```